# A number with $d$ digits in basis $b$ requires at most $\lceil dlog_cb \rceil$ bits to be written in basis $c$

Tags: binary, decimal-expansion

I know that a decimal number with $d$ digits requires at most $\lceil d\log_210 \rceil$ bits to be written in binary representation.

I'm trying to prove the general claim:

> For every $b,c>1$: a number with $d$ digits in basis $b$ requires at most $\lceil d\log_cb \rceil$ bits to be written in basis $c$ representation.

I tried to use to claim that a number $N$ with $d$ digits in any basis upholds that $b^{d-1} \leq N \leq b^d$, and use logarithm rules but got stuck.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: MathJax hint:  If you put a backslash before common function names you get the right font and spacing, so \log x gives $\log x$ instead of log x giving $log x$

Comment: @RossMillikan Edited, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is that the number of base $c$ digits in $N$ is $\lceil \log_c (N+1) \rceil$, which comes from the same consideration as $b^{d-1} \leq N \lt b^d$ (note the change to the upper less than sign).  Written in base $c$ it has $\lceil \log_c (N+1) \rceil \le \lceil \log_c b^d \rceil=\lceil d\log_c b \rceil$ digits

Comment: I know that $b^{d-1} \leq N \lt b^d \Rightarrow \lfloor log_cN+1 \rfloor$, why is true for the ceiling function as well? And could you please explain the first inequality in the last line?

Comment: Note that for the ceiling version the $+1$ is inside the argument of the $\log$ unlike the floor version.  The $+1$ takes care of the carry when $N$ is a power of $c$.  Think about $N=99$ and $N=100$ in base $10$.  For the last line, I just used $N+1 \le b^d$ and plugged it in.  That is why I cared about the $\leq$ really being $\lt$.  It let me absorb the $+1$

Comment: I see, how can I prove that identity for the ceiling function?

Comment: You use the relation in the end of your question, take the log, and round up.  You have $b^{d-1} \le N \le b^d-1, (d-1) \le \log_b (N+1) \le d$ and take ceilings.

Comment: I did that, but that's $\log$ with in $b$. How do I get $\log$ with in base $c$?

Comment: It works the same when you write in base $c$.  Look at my last line.  I took the log base $c$ of $b^d$ which is where the factor $\log_c b$ comes from.